# IE9 3d surface chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, internet-explorer-9, html5-canvas

I'm looking for an API or some sort of solution to do 3d surface charts within IE9, and I like how [javascript-surface-plot](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/) works, but it does not work in IE9.

Are there any other ways to do 3d rendering like that for charts in IE9?

I'm using Telerik controls for my other charts, but they do not seem to have a 3d surface chart.

I've also considered the use of a java applet, but would like to keep the load lightweight.

Flash is not an option.

Just to clarify, when I say "3d" I don't mean shiny bar charts. I mean a x,y,z rendered scene that can be rotated with the mouse similar to how java-script-surface-plot is done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this, but [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) looks pretty cool and might do the job.  Take a look at [this](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stream.html) example.

Edit:

After further investigation, I'm not sure that's what you'd need, though d3 does look pretty good, wouldn't you admit?

It does appear it'd be pretty easy to change it to work in IE9
take a look at this function in [SurfacePlot.js](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/source/browse/trunk/javascript/SurfacePlot.js)

```
    function createCanvas()
    {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

            if (isIE())
            {
                    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
                    canvas.style.width = width;
                    canvas.style.height = height;
            }

          //...rest of the code here
    }
```

It'd bee tempted to just remove those lines relating to `isIE()` in your local copy and say if you're using IE8, be damned !  (That or attempt to use [Flash Canvas](http://flashcanvas.net/)).  IE8 has little support for VML, and I think excanvas runs even slower in IE8 than IE7.

Comment: d3 does look snazzy, but it seems like a difficult graph to read aside from not being a 3d surface chart as well. Thanks for the response!

Comment: The IE detection is what did it. Although, it doesn't work in anything below IE9 now. Fortunately that fulfills my requirements! :) I just set that isIE() function to return false and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you like the [3D surface plot in JavaScript](http://www.grvisualisation.50webs.com/javascript_surface_plot.html) and you want to use IE it seems as though you just need to take use of [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) (a polyfill) to make it work in IE. It's just adding another JavaScript file though, and this way you don't need to use any plugins or applets!

Comment: Ah, but if this was created before IE9, they might just assume that you have to use excanvas with any version of IE and not do feature detection properly.

Comment: EDIT: Seems like we posted back-to-back!
In IE9 yes. Just checked the URL using IE9 and seems like it doesn't work. Odd seeing as how support for IE6 is mentioned. Probably the feature detection issue that you mentioned. Code could probably be easily tweaked to work in IE9!

Comment: I did download their demo and added excanvas, but I do admit I didn't try any further tweaking than the instructions for using excanvas. I'll give that a go for a bit and post back here the results. I really don't want to have to write my own using a Java applet. Thanks!

Comment: I got it to work in IE9. The IE detection was abysmal and I just set it to return false on the IsIE() and everything works fine with excanvas. Thank you!!

Comment: You could even try without excanvas, as IE9 should have full support for the canvas element. Glad to hear you got it working though!

Answer (score 1):

Oops. Looks like my isIE() function was well out of date. I've now added better IE and canvas-support detection to the surface plot. Sorry for the hassle. http://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/downloads/detail?name=JSSurfacePlot-V1.5.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Excellent! I'll check it out. Also cool you found this on SO :)